# Magento 2 reindex cronjob frequency

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex

Magento 2.3.0

It's more like an open question than a problem.

By default reindex by schedule is fired every minute. Why is that so often?

By your experience, can default cronjob be set less often and what are its consequences?